# Array.Sort is changing unspecified arrays in unity

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, unity-game-engine

I am trying to sort an array, and a list of indices, but I want the original array to stay the same.

When I use the Array.Sort() function, it not only sorts the specified arrays, but also the fitnessVals array (see code below). Does anyone know why this is, and what I can do to stop it from happening?

My code:

```
        tempFitnessVals = new float[numberOfItems];
        tempFitnessVals = fitnessVals;
        int[] indexes = new int[tempFitnessVals.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
        {
            indexes[i] = i;
        }
        Array.Sort(tempFitnessVals, indexes);
        Array.Reverse(tempFitnessVals);
        Array.Reverse(indexes);
```

Comment: `tempFitnessVals = fitnessVals` -> there is only a single array (with two names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code makes a reference and causes the issue you are facing:

```cs
tempFitnessVals = fitnessVals;
```

You need to replace this line with `Array.Copy`:

```cs
...
Array.Copy(fitnessVals, tempFitnessVals, numberOfItems);
...
```

Comment: For the record, it's simpler to just use LINQ these days: `tempFitnessVals = fitnessVals.ToArrayt();`.